# How to match a string inside another string while ignoring whitespace

Tags: javascript, string, match

I have a string to search, and I need to match and return another string at the beginning of the search string. The string being searched may have whitespace in it, which needs to be ignored for the purpose of searching, but still returned accurately. The string to be matched will never have whitespace in it.

```
stringA = "ThisIsAString";
```

Should give the following results when compared to stringB:

```
stringB = "This    Is A String";    //"This    Is A String"
stringB = "ThisIsAlsoAString";    //undefined
stringB = "ThisIs A String With Extra Words At The End";    //"ThisIs A String"
stringB = "Hey, ThisIsAString";     //undefined
```

What's an efficient way to do this?

Comment: A crazy solution, remove all the spaces to do the comparaison... The complication would be to get the original String from that. The unefficient way is to iteration the String and check character per character the `StringA`, from there, you could skip the space yourself. I don't know Regex enough to know if there is an equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\s*` to match zero or more spaces. With the code below we put one of those matchers between each character.

```js
const stringA = "ThisIsAString";


const tests = [
  "This    Is A String",
  "ThisIsAlsoAString",
  "ThisIs A String With Extra Words At The End",
  "Hey, ThisIsAString",
];

const optionalSpaces = '\\s*';


const results = tests.map(test =>
  test.match(
    new RegExp(stringA.split('').join(optionalSpaces))
  )
);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Yep, split-join is cleaner than my regex.

Comment: Was hoping for something a bit more elegant :P. This works though.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to remove all white space from the two things you are comparing.

```
var search = "Hello There";
var text = "HelloThere I'm Greg";
var found = text.replace(/ +?/g, '').indexOf(search.replace(/ +?/g, '')) !== -1;
```

Comment: The problem is, they also need the matching part.

Comment: That is easily done by returning `search` if `found` = true.

Comment: Yep, but they need to return the matching part of `text`, not the `search` string itself.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work, as georg said. I need to actually know what I matched, not just that there was a match.